# How do I use Xperia Ray through Eclipse for Android programming?

Tags: eclipse, usb, drivers

I downloaded the Suite for the phone, the Google USB drivers and the Phone's connection drivers. So far, the phone works perfectly with the PC but Eclipse still refuses to see the phone and Device Manager is convincing me that I have no hardware compatible with the Google USB drivers. Therefore the Google USB drivers are downloaded but not installed or assigned to any device. I followed every answer on stackoverflow that there is so far, but none have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, set your device into USB / debug mode.
- Second, after you connect your device to the USB make sure your drivers is installed properly.
- And last verify that adb.exe can detect you device from cmd (if running in windows) ..(path to your SDK)\platform-tools\adb device
- If last step fails, then re-install you device driver, it should be handled automatically by sony pc-companion for your xperia phone.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to enable `USB-Debugging` in `Settings->Developer Options` on your phone.